# how to filter rows between dates without using loop in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to filter rows from a single table between two datetimes and those filtered rows should come under a single date, for example

i want to get all the rows between 
(16 mar 2015 6AM) and (17 mar 2015 6AM) datetimes as (17 mar 2015) date and
(17 mar 2015 6AM) and (18 mar 2015 6AM) datetimes as (18 mar 2015) date and so on.

this is my demo table

```
Id      Name    LogTime
1       mj      2015-03-16 01:28:03.257
2       mj      2015-03-16 05:28:03.257
3       mj      2015-03-16 06:28:03.257
4       mj      2015-03-16 18:28:03.257
5       mj      2015-03-17 01:28:06.677
6       mj      2015-03-17 06:28:06.677
7       mj      2015-03-17 16:28:07.460
8       mj      2015-03-17 07:28:03.257
9       mj      2015-03-18 01:28:08.193
10      mj      2015-03-18 05:28:03.257
11      mj      2015-03-18 06:28:03.257
12      mj      2015-03-18 18:28:03.257
13      mj      2015-03-19 01:28:06.677
14      mj      2015-03-19 06:28:06.677
15      mj      2015-03-19 16:28:07.460
16      mj      2015-03-19 07:28:03.257
17      mj      2015-03-20 01:28:08.193
18      mj      2015-03-20 05:28:03.257
19      mj      2015-03-20 06:28:03.257
20      mj      2015-03-20 18:28:03.257
```

below is the query that I am using.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1

DECLARE @from DATETIME
    ,   @to DATETIME

WHILE (@i <= 5)
BEGIN

    SET @from = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(D, -@i, '2015-03-20'), 102) + ' 6:00:00')
    SET @to = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(D, -@i + 1, '2015-03-20'), 102) + ' 6:00:00')

    SELECT  *,  @to AS 'FetchedOn'
    FROM Biometric
    WHERE LogTime BETWEEN @from AND @to
    ORDER BY LogTime

    SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

that generates the following result.

```
Id  Name    LogTime             FetchedOn
14  mj  2015-03-19 06:28:06.677 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
16  mj  2015-03-19 07:28:03.257 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
15  mj  2015-03-19 16:28:07.460 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
17  mj  2015-03-20 01:28:08.193 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
18  mj  2015-03-20 05:28:03.257 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000

Id  Name    LogTime             FetchedOn
11  mj  2015-03-18 06:28:03.257 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
12  mj  2015-03-18 18:28:03.257 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
13  mj  2015-03-19 01:28:06.677 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000

Id  Name    LogTime             FetchedOn
6   mj  2015-03-17 06:28:06.677 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
8   mj  2015-03-17 07:28:03.257 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
7   mj  2015-03-17 16:28:07.460 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
9   mj  2015-03-18 01:28:08.193 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
10  mj  2015-03-18 05:28:03.257 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000

Id  Name    LogTime             FetchedOn
3   mj  2015-03-16 06:28:03.257 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
4   mj  2015-03-16 18:28:03.257 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
5   mj  2015-03-17 01:28:06.677 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000

Id  Name    LogTime             FetchedOn
1   mj  2015-03-16 01:28:03.257 2015-03-16 06:00:00.000
2   mj  2015-03-16 05:28:03.257 2015-03-16 06:00:00.000
```

now I want to get the same result without using loop.
I am using sql 2014, is there any alternate solution?

Comment: You can use CLR table valued function. It might be faster, than t-sql while loop.

Comment: By "same result" do you mean five _separate_ result sets or would you accept a single result set with an `i` column to group the results by date?

Comment: no of tables doesn't matter for me, as long as it returns the correct result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate FetchedOn based on the time part of the LogTime field:

```
SELECT B.*,  dateadd(day, (iif(cast(LogTime as time) < '06:00:00', 0, 1)), cast(LogTime as date)) + cast('06:00:00' as datetime) as FetchedOn
from Biometric B
ORDER BY FetchedOn DESC, LogTime
```

**Update:**

Simpler formula to calculate FetchedOn, and also a cast to `datetime` added for SQL2012+ compatibility.

```
SELECT B.*, cast(cast(dateadd(hour, +18, LogTime) as date) as datetime) + cast('06:00:00' as datetime) as FetchedOn
from Biometric B
ORDER BY FetchedOn DESC, LogTime
```

Comment: All other answers so far are simple code dumps without any explanation whatsoever. Your answer is much shorter, but it explains (if only briefly) the reasoning behind a working solution. +1 for that.

Comment: @stakx, are you serious? I will shut my eyes on everything but this code simply doesn't work.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Possible, *but* it's the only answer that cares to explain how you could get a working solution. To me that is *much* more helpful than a copy-paste-style answer.

Comment: First you have syntax error in dateadd, because you are using date type there, it is error. You return all rows. Op return only 18 rows. But the idea is correct and you need to correct those errors

Comment: There is no syntax errors since DateAdd accepts a date as its third parameter. And this a sample data, you can always add a where clause to justify the results.

Comment: I mean in dateadd function you have date + datetime, this is illegal: `Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.
`

Comment: iif would never work in sql 2008, its sql 2012 and later

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code. The Idea is to get all possible distinct ranges from test data. This is what CTE returns:

```
st                      ed
2015-03-15 06:00:00.000 2015-03-16 06:00:00.000
2015-03-16 06:00:00.000 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
2015-03-17 06:00:00.000 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
2015-03-18 06:00:00.000 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
2015-03-19 06:00:00.000 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
```

After this it simple join on condition where data falls between those ranges:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT, D DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1       ,'2015-03-16 01:28:03.257'),
(2       ,'2015-03-16 05:28:03.257'),
(3       ,'2015-03-16 06:28:03.257'),
(4       ,'2015-03-16 18:28:03.257'),
(5       ,'2015-03-17 01:28:06.677'),
(6       ,'2015-03-17 06:28:06.677'),
(7       ,'2015-03-17 16:28:07.460'),
(8       ,'2015-03-17 07:28:03.257'),
(9       ,'2015-03-18 01:28:08.193'),
(10      ,'2015-03-18 05:28:03.257'),
(11      ,'2015-03-18 06:28:03.257'),
(12      ,'2015-03-18 18:28:03.257'),
(13      ,'2015-03-19 01:28:06.677'),
(14      ,'2015-03-19 06:28:06.677'),
(15      ,'2015-03-19 16:28:07.460'),
(16      ,'2015-03-19 07:28:03.257'),
(17      ,'2015-03-20 01:28:08.193'),
(18      ,'2015-03-20 05:28:03.257'),
(19      ,'2015-03-20 06:28:03.257'),
(20      ,'2015-03-20 18:28:03.257')

;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        DATEADD(HOUR, -18, CAST(CAST(D AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS st ,
                        DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CAST(CAST(D AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS ed
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  t.ID, t.D, c.ed
    FROM    cte c
            JOIN @t t ON t.D BETWEEN c.st AND c.ed
```

Output:

```
ID  D                       ed
1   2015-03-16 01:28:03.257 2015-03-16 06:00:00.000
2   2015-03-16 05:28:03.257 2015-03-16 06:00:00.000
3   2015-03-16 06:28:03.257 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
4   2015-03-16 18:28:03.257 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
5   2015-03-17 01:28:06.677 2015-03-17 06:00:00.000
6   2015-03-17 06:28:06.677 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
7   2015-03-17 16:28:07.460 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
8   2015-03-17 07:28:03.257 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
9   2015-03-18 01:28:08.193 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
10  2015-03-18 05:28:03.257 2015-03-18 06:00:00.000
11  2015-03-18 06:28:03.257 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
12  2015-03-18 18:28:03.257 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
13  2015-03-19 01:28:06.677 2015-03-19 06:00:00.000
14  2015-03-19 06:28:06.677 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
15  2015-03-19 16:28:07.460 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
16  2015-03-19 07:28:03.257 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
17  2015-03-20 01:28:08.193 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
18  2015-03-20 05:28:03.257 2015-03-20 06:00:00.000
```

Comment: I did. I suppose your answer is not incorrect, but what bothers me about it is that there is no explanation whatsoever what that "some code" does. Your answer would be so much *more helpful if* it wasn't just a code / result dump, but if these were accompanied with at least a brief explanation of the thinking behind it. I would be happy to upvote if the question were edited accordingly.

Comment: I will update but I really think that there is nothing to comment. Code is selfexplanatory in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula that should work for SQL Server 2005+: `DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, 18, A.LogTime) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))`. We simply add 18 hours to the LogTime, abuse CAST to truncate the time piece off, and then add 6 hours to this value.

**Full Example (based on original):**

```
DECLARE @i INT = 5
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2015-03-20 06:00:00.000';
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = DATEADD(d, -@i, @endDate);

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.Id
         , A.LogTime
         , FetchedOn = DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, 18, A.LogTime) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
    FROM(VALUES
        (1, '2015-03-16 01:28:03.257')
      , (2, '2015-03-16 05:28:03.257')
      , (3, '2015-03-16 06:28:03.257')
      , (4, '2015-03-16 18:28:03.257')
      , (5, '2015-03-17 01:28:06.677')
      , (6, '2015-03-17 06:28:06.677')
      , (7, '2015-03-17 16:28:07.460')
      , (8, '2015-03-17 07:28:03.257')
      , (9, '2015-03-18 01:28:08.193')
      , (10, '2015-03-18 05:28:03.257')
      , (11, '2015-03-18 06:28:03.257')
      , (12, '2015-03-18 18:28:03.257')
      , (13, '2015-03-19 01:28:06.677')
      , (14, '2015-03-19 06:28:06.677')
      , (15, '2015-03-19 16:28:07.460')
      , (16, '2015-03-19 07:28:03.257')
      , (17, '2015-03-20 01:28:08.193')
      , (18, '2015-03-20 05:28:03.257')
      , (19, '2015-03-20 06:28:03.257')
      , (20, '2015-03-20 18:28:03.257')
    ) A (Id, LogTime)
    WHERE A.LogTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
) A
ORDER BY A.FetchedOn DESC, A.LogTime ASC;
```